# How to set a box on CameraX preview so as to processes it using ImageAnalysis in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

I have been working on an app which needed to use CameraX for it's preview stream but it also needs a box kind of overlay from which the text will be decoded. I have successfully implemented the preview but for can't seem to find a way to implement an overlay from which the text will be decoded without using any third party application. Right now we can decode text from the entire screen. I have seen a code that does just this in Codelabs turtorial ([link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android-translate/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4)) but it's in Kotlin and I can't decipher this complex Kotlin code. If anyone can help me do this without using third party library,it would be great. Thanks in advance.

my XML code:

```
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
android:id="@+id/previewView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="675dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">
```

my camera logic:

```
PreviewView mCameraView;
Camera camera;
void startCamera() {
  mCameraView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

  cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

  cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
      try {
          ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
          bindPreview(cameraProvider);
      } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
          // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
          // This should never be reached.
      }
  }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
}



void bindPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {


  Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().
        setTargetResolution(BestSize())
        .build();

CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        .build();

preview.setSurfaceProvider(mCameraView.createSurfaceProvider());

ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(new Size(4000, 5000))
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build();

imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, image -> {
        frames++;
        int rotationDegrees = degreesToFirebaseRotation(image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());

        Image mediaImage = image.getImage();
        if (mediaImage == null) {
            return;
        }

        FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, 
       rotationDegrees);

        FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = 
          FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();

        detector.processImage(firebaseVisionImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener(firebaseVisionText -> {
                    // Task completed successfully
                    String text = firebaseVisionText.getText();
                    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
                        if (firstValidFrame == 0)
                            firstValidFrame = frames;
                        validFrames++;
                    }
                    mTextView.setText(text);
                    image.close();
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        e -> {
                            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
                            image.close();
                        });
    });
camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview);

}

private int degreesToFirebaseRotation(int degrees) {
  switch (degrees) {
      case 0:
          return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0;
      case 90:
          return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90;
      case 180:
          return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180;
      case 270:
          return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270;
      default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "Rotation must be 0, 90, 180, or 270.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out how to do it and I wrote an article with a demo repo for those who are having the same problem that I had. Here is the link:
https://medium.com/@sdptd20/exploring-ocr-capabilities-of-ml-kit-using-camera-x-9949633af0fe

1. So basically what I did was get the frames from the Camera X preview using Image Analysis.
2. Then I created a surface view on top of the preview and drew a rectangle on it.
3. Then I took the offset of the rectangle and cropped my bitmap according to that.
4. And then I fed the bitmaps to the FirebaseImageAnalyzer and I got the text that's displayed in the bounding box only.

Here is the gist of the main activity:
`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    TextView textView;
    PreviewView mCameraView;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;
    int cameraHeight, cameraWidth, xOffset, yOffset, boxWidth, boxHeight;

    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    /**
     *Responsible for converting the rotation degrees from CameraX into the one compatible with Firebase ML
     */

    private int degreesToFirebaseRotation(int degrees) {
        switch (degrees) {
            case 0:
                return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0;
            case 90:
                return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90;
            case 180:
                return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180;
            case 270:
                return FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Rotation must be 0, 90, 180, or 270.");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Starting Camera
     */
    void startCamera(){
        mCameraView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);

        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    MainActivity.this.bindPreview(cameraProvider);
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
                    // This should never be reached.
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }

    /**
     *
     * Binding to camera
     */
    private void bindPreview(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                .build();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(mCameraView.createSurfaceProvider());

        //Image Analysis Function
        //Set static size according to your device or write a dynamic function for it
        ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
                new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                        .setTargetResolution(new Size(720, 1488))
                        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                        .build();


        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
            @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
            @Override
            public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                //changing normal degrees into Firebase rotation
                int rotationDegrees = degreesToFirebaseRotation(image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());
                if (image == null || image.getImage() == null) {
                    return;
                }
                //Getting a FirebaseVisionImage object using the Image object and rotationDegrees
                final Image mediaImage = image.getImage();
                FirebaseVisionImage images = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotationDegrees);
                //Getting bitmap from FirebaseVisionImage Object
                Bitmap bmp=images.getBitmap();
                //Getting the values for cropping
                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                int height = bmp.getHeight();
                int width = bmp.getWidth();

                int left, right, top, bottom, diameter;

                diameter = width;
                if (height < width) {
                    diameter = height;
                }

                int offset = (int) (0.05 * diameter);
                diameter -= offset;


                left = width / 2 - diameter / 3;
                top = height / 2 - diameter / 3;
                right = width / 2 + diameter / 3;
                bottom = height / 2 + diameter / 3;

                xOffset = left;
                yOffset = top;

                //Creating new cropped bitmap
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, left, top, boxWidth, boxHeight);
                //initializing FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer object
                FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                        .getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
                //Passing FirebaseVisionImage Object created from the cropped bitmap
                Task<FirebaseVisionText> result =  detector.processImage(FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                                // Task completed successfully
                                // ...
                                textView=findViewById(R.id.text);
                                //getting decoded text
                                String text=firebaseVisionText.getText();
                                //Setting the decoded text in the texttview
                                textView.setText(text);
                                //for getting blocks and line elements
                                for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block: firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks()) {
                                    String blockText = block.getText();
                                    for (FirebaseVisionText.Line line: block.getLines()) {
                                        String lineText = line.getText();
                                        for (FirebaseVisionText.Element element: line.getElements()) {
                                            String elementText = element.getText();

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                image.close();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        // Task failed with an exception
                                        // ...
                                        Log.e("Error",e.toString());
                                        image.close();
                                    }
                                });
            }


        });
        Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis,preview);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Start Camera
        startCamera();

        //Create the bounding box
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.overlay);
        surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
        holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.addCallback(this);

    }

    /**
     *
     * For drawing the rectangular box
     */
    private void DrawFocusRect(int color) {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = mCameraView.getHeight();
        int width = mCameraView.getWidth();

        //cameraHeight = height;
        //cameraWidth = width;

        int left, right, top, bottom, diameter;

        diameter = width;
        if (height < width) {
            diameter = height;
        }

        int offset = (int) (0.05 * diameter);
        diameter -= offset;

        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        //border's properties
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        left = width / 2 - diameter / 3;
        top = height / 2 - diameter / 3;
        right = width / 2 + diameter / 3;
        bottom = height / 2 + diameter / 3;

        xOffset = left;
        yOffset = top;
        boxHeight = bottom - top;
        boxWidth = right - left;
        //Changing the value of x in diameter/x will change the size of the box ; inversely proportionate to x
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Callback functions for the surface Holder
     */

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        //Drawing rectangle
        DrawFocusRect(Color.parseColor("#b3dabb"));
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

`

Edit: I have found that you can use a png file with an image view instead of the surface view too. That may be cleaner and you can also integrate a customised layout for the users to superimpose on.

Edit2: I have found that sending bitmap to image analyser can be inefficient ( was working on MLKit Barcode reader and it explicitly throws this warning in the logs) so what we can do is:

```
imagePreview.setCropRect(r);
```

where imagePreview is the ImageProxy image and r is the "android.graphics.Rect".

Comment: I understood till image analysis but if I want to capture the view shown by my analyzer what can I do?

Comment: @AsthaGarg The image has already been converted into a bitmap in the imageAnalysis function. You can just save that bmp in the local storage.

Answer (score 2):

This is the basically the logic in the codelab do:

1. Convert the Image object to a bitmap: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/blob/master/translate/starter/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/codelab/translate/analyzer/TextAnalyzer.kt#L65
2. Crop the bitmap to the given box: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/blob/master/translate/starter/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/codelab/translate/analyzer/TextAnalyzer.kt#L95
3. Then you can send the cropped image to text recognition.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help...I had already figured it out though and I was thinking about answering my own question lol
I didn't think I will get an answer to this question lol